# Oracle Apex script editor disabled

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am looking for help, with a frustrating problem. My script editor highlights red and is disabled i.e I can type nothing into it. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: I have seen this but can't remember if I rectified it with different browser or something else. Check browser console for errors. And upgrade your APEX env!

Comment: I remember getting this issue on earlier versions of Apex (e.g. 2.2). The fix in my case was to add two lines to my apache config: `AddType text/xml xbl` `AddType text/x-component htc`

Comment: Thanks guys..however not solved